# Column-count list reorders when expanding child items

Tags: html, css, column-count

I'm using `column-count: 3` to divide a list into three columns and styles each list item with `display: inline-block` to keep the list item´s children in the same column. The children are hidden with `max-height` and `overflow: hidden`.

I want to expand and show the children on click by setting `max-height: none`, but since column-count tries to evenly balance all columns dynamically the list gets reordered. I understand that's what column-count is for.

I would like to use something similar to `column-count: 3` but "lock" it after page load so it doesn't reorder when expanding children. Would that be possible without splitting the items into three different lists? The *only* requirement is that it works on IE11.

[Here is my codepen demo](http://codepen.io/calsal/pen/QpRmRN) to illustrate the problem.

Comment: I assume the list items will be dynamic (i.e. the number will change), so you can't hard code them into three divs?

Comment: If you're using JavaScript for the functionality anyway, you can build the three lists programmatically on page load.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I guess I could split them up with javascript but I have a rather large menu (5+ different entries, each have three columns) and I guess it's not efficient to build three lists for every entry.
The numbers won't change, it's always 3. The only solution I can think of yet is to hard code them into different divs in backend.